# Enumitem - How to get custom label in line with the margin

Tags: enumitem

I have the following very basic question concerning the behavior of `enumitem`:

> How do we make a custom (potentially long) label be in line with the margin?

Take the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}[label=Counter \arabic*]
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

How do we make the label `Counter \arabic*` be in line with the margins provided by the file?
*[Of course the answer should be robust to the usage of additional packages such as `geometry` and it should not consist of some trial-and-error with `leftmargin`in the options.]*

Also, a counter that gets at most **one** digit (from 1 to 9) is fine, just to avoid aligning with potential multiple digits.

Thanks a lot for any feedback.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can have one of these, for instance, depending on where you want to have the list left margin:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{enumerate}[label=Counter \arabic*. , wide=0pt, font=\itshape]
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\begin{enumerate}[label=Counter \arabic*., wide=0pt, leftmargin=*]
\item \blindtext
\item \blindtext
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great and supercomplete answer!

Comment: I am coming back to this great answer, because I am wondering how it can be applied to itemize instead of enumerate, e.g., say "Counter 1" is obtained as \item[Counter 1]. Should I add something more? It seems to me this is the case, since I do not get the desire output.

Comment: I don't quite see what you'd like to obtain with itemize. Some text  followed by a bullet?

Comment: I actually fixed the problem. I went back to a previous answer of yours, found out what I was supposed to do and played around with labelindent. :)

Comment: Fine! Was my interpretation of what you wanted to obtain correct?

Comment: No. I actually wanted to get a text, say "Foo", instead of a bullett, to then get the second kind of output you produced, i.e., one in which the text after the item does not get below the item. Basically, exactly what you got with your second kind of output, but without enumerate and with a text that could change from item to item. [Not sure I explained myself]

Comment: Per  curiosity, did you use a custom description?

Comment: Not sure what you mean (I am very ignorant... :)...), but I just put itemize with labelindent with a space option along with leftmargin=* and that made the job.